# Exclude some of the files with rsync

Tags: command-line, rsync

I want to do `rsync` from the folder e.g. `/user/home/ford` , and I have a directory named `xthp` inside ford; so now i want to exclude few of the files
from the directory `xthp`.

I am using the command given below:

```
rsync -vax --exclude-from=/user/home/ford/xthp/excld.txt /user/home/ford/ destination-path
```

The files I want to exclude are listed in `excld.txt` but I am not able to do this.

Comment: Are the file names newline separated in `excld.txt` ? Also are you copying to the same filesystem?

Comment: Yes, files are new line separated and same type of file system. Within the excld.txt , I wrote like: sng.dat, then in new line, fkg.dat .....

Comment: Use absolute paths, not relative paths..

Comment: I am using absolute paths only !

Comment: Can't reproduce..

Answer (score 2):

Yes This is correct your command not working *-vax*:

I just tried with:

```
rsync -vax --exclude-from=/var/www/html/exclude.txt /var/www/html/test/ /var/www/html/test/
```

My *exclude.txt* example file are like below:

```
- /var/www/html/.git
+ /var/www/html/*.php
```

Or

```
.git

app/
```

Here is your command modified just give try with it:

```
rsync -vax --exclude-from=/user/home/ford/xthp/excld.txt /user/home/ford/ destination-path
```

More at [exclude-from](https://sites.google.com/site/rsync2u/home/rsync-tutorial/the-exclude-from-option)

Output:

```
rsync -vax --exclude-from=/var/www/html/exclude.txt  /var/www/html/test/ /var/www/html/test
sending incremental file list
./

sent 104,153 bytes  received 624 bytes  209,554.00 bytes/sec
total size is 153,940,108  speedup is 1,469.22
```

- A leading "+" means include the pattern.  A leading "-" means exclude the pattern.

Comment: rsync: failed to open exclude file /user/home/ford/xthp/excld.txt: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at exclude.c(1062) [client=3.0.6]

Comment: could you please check like  _rsync -avz --exclude-from=/var/www/html/exclude.txt  /var/www/html/test/ /var/www/html/test_  it's ok here ...sending incremental file list..sent 397,400 bytes  received 2,784 bytes  800,368.00 bytes/sec

Comment: I think he is using script to run rsync. maybe this is the problem.